# How can I programmatically update the _wc_average_rating meta field in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce website that has a custom review system. I want to show the same reviews for multiple products that are variations but have their own product page.

Still I want to be able to sort products based on their rating, so I want to programmatically update '_wc_average_rating' whenever a custom review is placed. Also the rich data markup is using these fields to populate the rich data markup.

I'm using the following code to update the meta values.

```
update_post_meta( 13566, '_wc_review_count', 4);
update_post_meta( 13566, '_wc_rating_count', 4);
update_post_meta( 13566, '_wc_average_rating', 5.00);
```

For the review and rating count it is working fine, but for the average rating it's not working.

I tried different things, like:

```
update_post_meta( 13566, '_wc_average_rating', 5.00); 
update_post_meta( 13566, '_wc_average_rating', 5); 
update_post_meta( 13566, '_wc_average_rating', '5.00');
```

How can I update the _wc_average_rating meta field? Is there a function to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: “Custom” review system means what, exactly? Something you yourself wrote? Or some 3rd-party plugin? Where/when do the `update_post_meta` calls you have shown happen, could it be that this simply gets _overwritten_ later?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? The call to update_post_meta is quite simple, i don't see (based from the code you posted) any reason of why it shouldn't work. My guess is that there's some other call to update_post_meta on that field that invalidates your saving

Comment: Custom review system is indeed something I wrote myself. I tried updating the meta values within the wordpress 'init' hook.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following code to verify your approach, and on my site its totally working. My average rating for my product 249 gets changed to 2:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    $product = wc_get_product( 249 );
    error_log( $product->get_average_rating( 'edit' ) );
    update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wc_average_rating', 2.00 );
} );
```

If you check this image - my first rating set the average rating to 5 and I changed it with my code to 2:

[image]

So I really don't know what's not working on your site. I just can confirm that updating the average rating is possible the way I showed you.

Maybe you can show me the place where you execute your code. Sometimes this may be the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it. I'm running it from functions.php, the same way as you do it right there. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @LuukVanDongen maybe your site has some sort of caching or you need to clear the transients? Looking at the WooCommerce source code you are using the same method. Perhaps some child/parent configuration which looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

My website is running WPML, and that plugin uses it's own 2 meta fields to sync rating/reviews across different languages. The meta fields are:

```
_wcml_average_rating
_wcml_review_count
```

So to update the rating in a WPML website, you need to update all these fields:

```
update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wc_review_count', $count);
update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wc_rating_count', $count);
update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wcml_review_count', $count);
update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wcml_average_rating', $rating);
update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wc_average_rating', $rating);
```